# Using variable in IF clause

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I´m programming some Form in Access 2010 and want to check some Radio Button if they are checked or not.

I want to use an until Loop because there are 38 questions which would be to much to check by every row.

I used this but it´s not working

```
Me.OptionQ(lNum).Value
```

Here´s the complete IF statement I want to use.

```
Dim lNum AS Long

lNum = 1


Do Until lNum = 39


 If Me.OptionQ(lNum).Value = 1 Then
     MsgBox "Option 1 is selected"
 ElseIf Me.OptionQ(lNum).Value = 2 Then
     MsgBox "Option 2 is selected"
 ElseIf Me.OptionQ(lNum).Value = 3 Then
     MsgBox "Option 3 is selected"
 Else
     MsgBox "Please choose an answer for every question."
     Exit Do
 End If
lNum = lNum + 1

Loop
```

I searched a lot, but it seems there is no way to do it like this.

Comment: **How** is it not working?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with Me.OptionQ(lNum).Value

Comment: **How** is it not working? What's wrong? Does it explode?

Comment: Compile error: Method or data member not found       I think this is caused on the name of the Label with the Buttons. The name on the Form is OptionQ1 OptionQ2 OptionQ3 and so on and I want to have the numers in a value

Comment: Next time, you should tell us what you're trying to do, and what the problem is, instead of leaving us to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying you have a set of 38 controls named *OptionQ1* through *OptionQ38*.

If that is correct, you can inspect the value of each of those controls and do what you want with simpler code.

```vb
For lNum = 1 To 38
    Select Case Me.Controls("OptionQ" & lNum).Value
    Case 1 To 3
        MsgBox "Option " & Me.Controls("OptionQ" & lNum).Value & _
            " is selected"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Please choose an answer for every question."
        Exit For
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: And yes, that´s what I wanted to do.